# Kendo grid cannot update "dirty"

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid in my project and i want to do a "unsaved changes" prompt if user made changes on the item inside the grid. What i think about is check for "dirty" field in the e.model. However, the "dirty" always show false even though there is an changes.

This is my code for datasource

```
        var fieldDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: gridData,
                pageSize: 50,
                change: function (e) {
                    if (e.action == "itemchange") {
                        e.items[0].dirtyFields = e.items[0].dirtyFields || {};
                        e.items[0].dirtyFields[e.field] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle there this behavior could be seen?

Answer (score 0):

for dirty to change from false to true, you must use the method observable.set if not it won't see your changes.

```
let dirtyFields = e.items[0].get('dirtyFields');
if (!dirtyFields) {
    let t = {};
    t[e.field] = true;
    e.items[0].set('dirtyFields', t);
} else {
    dirtyFields.set(e.field, t);
}
```